# Splitting IPTables output to a multidimensional array for database

Tags: php, arrays, linux, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the current IPTables rules in my Debian server neatly listed up in a database.

To do this, I've written a few steps.

1. First, we get the IPTables output with line number. (Input chain for example)

   iptables -L INPUT -nvx --line

I get a neat output, that I want to get in my database the exact same way.
For example;

```
Number, Chain, Protocol, Port, in, out
```

etcetera.

To get this output to be compatible with importing to the database, I need to get it into a multidimensional array. This is where I'm stuck. It's needs to be like this;

```
[0] (entry of rule)
[number],[chain],[protocol]...

[1]
[number],[chain],[protocol]
```

How exactly can I do this the most efficient way?

-- UPDATED CODE --

```
function getIPTables() {
$processHandle = popen('/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -L INPUT -nvx --line-numbers | tail -n +3', 'r');
$content = '';
    while (!feof($processHandle)) {
        $content .= fread($processHandle, 4096);
    }
pclose($processHandle);



// break out all new lines into an array
$lines = explode("\n", $content);


foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $commands = array();

    $segments = explode(" ", $line); 

    $newEntry = array(
        'Number'    =>  $segments[0],
        'Chain'     =>  $segments[1],
        'Protocol'  =>  $segments[2],
        'Port'      =>  $segments[3],
        'in'        =>  $segments[4],
        'out'       =>  $segments[5]
    );
    array_push($commands, $newEntry);
    print_r($commands);
}



}
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
root@debian:/home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES# php getAllRules
Local DB rules from users loaded in array 
 PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES/getAllRules on line 47
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES/getAllRules on line 48
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES/getAllRules on line 49
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES/getAllRules on line 50
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in /home/michael/Documents/PHPCLIFILES/getAllRules on line 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your regex's are correct. You're actually appending everything to the same string using `$commands .= <some text>`.
Rather than appending it to the same string, you should make `$commands` an array. Then you want to instantiate a new array for every line you go into (`$line`). `push` the things you want to keep onto your `$line` array, and at the end of every line you `array_push($commands, $line)`

`Array_push()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

this could be an approach for your `foreach()`

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $commands = new array;
    if (empty($line)) {
        continue; //empty lines are silly
    }
    // ... do all the checks to validate if you currently have a valid LINE
    //We know that whatever we have now is a valid line 
    $segments = explode(line bla bla); //explode this line on tabs or spaces .. dunno what the output of your console is.
    //At this point you know exactly where every part you need is, considering the console always gives the same output.
    //Either you do some validations here, or you go for the lazy approach and go:
    $newEntry = array(
        'Number'    =>  $segments[0],
        'Chain'     =>  $segments[1],
        'Protocol'  =>  $segments[2],
        'Port'      =>  $segments[3],
        'in'        =>  $segments[4],
        'out'       =>  $segments[5]
    );
    array_push($commands, $newentry);
}
```

code is not tested, but you should get an idea where i'm going to.

Your code:

```
//instantiate a new empty named variable.
$commands = '';
//for every line in your console-dump file
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    //Is the line empty
    if (empty($line)) {
        //skip line and go to next line
        continue;
    }
    //Does the line start with #
    if (preg_match('/^#/', $line) === 1) {
        //skip line and go to next line
        continue;
    }
    //Does the line start with *
    if (preg_match('/^\*/', $line) === 1) {
        //skip line and go to next line
        continue;
    }
    //Does the line start with 'COMMIT'
    if (preg_match('/^COMMIT/', $line) === 1) {
        //skip line and go to next line
        continue;
    }
    //we have a valid line now, so let's do stuff
    $match = array();
    //Does the line contain:
    if (preg_match('/^:([A-Z ]*).*/', $line, $match) === 1) {
        //skip line and go to next line
        continue;
    }
    //Only if the line is a 'valid' line, and does not have your last match,
    //Then you will append "iptables {$line}\n" to $commands
    $commands .= "iptables {$line}\n";
    //This way it was a bit useless for you to cut up the line using the preg_match
    //and store it into $match, cause you don't do anything with $match
}
```

Your initial approach is good. And depending how your console returns predictable
values, you either follow your approach with the regex (but then actually use the result) or you just go the lazy approach and use the one i suggested.

Do note that `CONTINUE` actually breaks your current loop, and goes into the next iteration.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach($array as $number){
    if($number < 3){
        continue;
    }
    print($number .'\n');
}
```

The outcome will be:

```
3\n
4\n
5\n
```

as continue actually completely stops this attempt in your `foreach()`

Comment: So what you're saying is; I'm currently pushing whole lines of rules through, and when it ends, I create a new line. However, I could stop at every stripe like -A and push that into a new stack?

Could you get me an example? I'm kind of an beginner to PHP so this is a bit advanced for me.

Comment: Edited my answer, i hope it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Looking through it now, and trying some things. I get your concept of approach and I appreciate it greatly!

Comment: I have looked through the code, however still something is wrong. I've posted my code in my original post. Can you see what's going wrong?

Comment: `$segments = explode(line bla bla);` xD ... you have to write the correct `explode()` thing. You'll need to select the character that your console writes seperate a value from the next.

Comment: My regex skills are not yet legendary, what does `preg_match('/^:([A-Z ]*).*/', $line,)` mean? and what does `print_r($commands);` print out? not much i assume? Oh, and post a few examples of the lines that your console has outputted please

Comment: Go ahead and take a look at my new approach. Updated my code and added some output. Everything is going right however I get the notice that the offsets aren't set. Something is apparently going wrong while transferring the lines into the array..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42848/discussion-between-viridis-and-michaelp)